# Extract PSD features from a 3D array that contains EEG data

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am new to EEG signal processing and I am trying to implement a function that calculates PSD features using Python.

The input of this function is a NumPy  3D-array called "trials", with size (240, 2047, 16) that contains EEG data in this form: (trials x time x channels)

I need to extract PSD features for the whole trial, for each channel and return an array of all the results.

Fs is 512Hz

This is my code so far:

```
from scipy import signal

def PSD(trials):
    psd = []
    fs = 512.
    
    for i in range(len(trials)):
        for j in range(len(trials[i])):
            f, Pxx = signal.welch(trials[i][j], fs, nperseg = 16)
            psd.append(Pxx)
        

    psd = np.array(psd)

    return psd
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this?

Comment: Probably, depends on what the definition of PSD features and if it's possible to extract these features with something other than two for loops.  For us to help you further, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) of `scipy.signal.welch`, by default the PSD is calculated over the last axis of the array.

This means you can do:

```
f, Pxx = scipy.signal.welch(trials, fs=512.0, nperseg=16)
```

`Pxx` is then of shape `(240, 2047, 9)`. In your example code, `psd` has shape `(491280, 9)`. If you would like your results to take this shape, simply reshape the array:

```
Pxx = Pxx.reshape(491280, 9)
```

Also, in your example code you append the sample frequencies to `psd` rather than the PSD, so your current code doesn't return the PSD.

Comment: Actually, I need to calculate PSD for each trial, for each channel, so should I loop over trials and then calculate PSD like this?  ``` f, Pxx = scipy.signal.welch(tr.T, fs=512.0,)```

Comment: THere's no need for any for loops - you can calculate the PSD over the first axis using the `axis` keyword: `f, Pxx = scipy.signal.welch(trials, fs=512.0, nperseg=16, axis=1)`